# Cut/Rearange background centered instead of resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little test site, where the width of a div gets decreased to 50% and another div appears when we click on button. 
Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/NdqqjR)

When you click on the button, the image just gets resized. 
Because I am using: `background-size: 100%;`
But I want the image to move a bit to the left, so that it gets centred.

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: There is a link to codepen.io with all of my code?

Comment: The image looks centered

Comment: Yes, but it gets resized. And I want that it doesn't resize and just moves.

Comment: I prefer do code all new. Many tuts you can learn how to deal with this : example https://demos.scotch.io/body-class-menus/reveal-right/demos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one simple thing you can do:

Just remove the bg image from `content-container div` and add it to the `body`

```
body{
  background: url("http://foto-muehlbacher.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Landschaft33-1.jpg");
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.new-content').toggleClass('half').delay(0).fadeIn(200);
  $('.content-container').toggleClass('half').style.width = "50%".backgroundSize = "200%";
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  background: url("http://foto-muehlbacher.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Landschaft33-1.jpg");
}
.content-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.new-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f60;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.new-content.half,
.content-container.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
  <div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<button id="button">
Click me
</button>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="new-content">
<p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: `Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 60,
  "colno": 59
}`

Comment: I don't know why this error is showing(I don't have much exp. in JS) but the problem you were having is resolved I think. Right?

Comment: The image doesn't shifts or resizes when the button is clicked and I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: My image should move a bit to the left on click. Like 25% or smth

Comment: Okay. I'll try if I can do that.